# Using AppCenter.ms trying to build for iOS, invalid p12 certificate

Tags: ios, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to build an ios app using the AppCenter.ms service, and I can get to the point where I have to upload the apple certificate but it tells me it's invalid even thought it is the same one I used to deploy my app before.

(I did it from a mac before, now I am doing it from windows which is why im using the appcenter.ms)

I am not sure how I need to fix the certificate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to export the certificate from Keychain from mac os

when you open the Keychain.app you need to search for the account holder name and export the certificate and upload to AppCenter.ms

Comment: Ok thanks, I will give that a go and report back. (Is there any way to do this on a windows machine btw?)

Comment: As far as I know there is no way